# old permalinks not found

Tags: permalinks, htaccess, 404-error

Looking through Google Webmaster Tools, I have a lot of 404s for posts with permalink structure of /%year%/%month%/%day%/%postname%/

I have since changed permalinks to /%category%/%postname%.html

I thought Wordpress could redirect old post URLs to new post URLS, but the old date based URLs are generating 404s.

My .htaccess file is writable, set to 644.

Why is this occurring?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress doesn’t catch *all* old URLs, you have to help it. Add the following code to your .htaccess *above* the WordPress rewrite rules:

```
RedirectMatch permanent /\d+/\d+/\d+/(.+)$ /?pagename=$1
```

Comment: It's not working now for some reason.

Comment: What happens instead?

Comment: Sorry, just a 404 error.

Comment: Does the URL change?

Comment: No, it remains.  The incorrect format is domain.com/postname - it should be domain.com/category/postname.

Comment: That is not the format you asked in your question. This cannot be handled per .htaccess because it is the same as the regular `page` format.